# Authenticate Active Directory User within a WCF Service

Tags: ios, asp.net, wcf, active-directory

I am writing an iOS application that I would like to send a login and password through a WCF service residing on an IIS server developed in C#.  I would like to verify that the USERNAME and PASSWORD is a valid Active Directory account.  If so, then I will log them into the application on the iOS device and continue on.  Is this possible?  My ASP.NET application that will be hosting this WCF service could be either in Windows or Forms authentication mode depending on the client.  Any code example that would allow me to use the passed credentials to verify that they are valid AD user credentials would be great.

Thanks